# Is "pointe de menton" really used in French?

Tags: sens, expressions

When I translate button, I have the translation "bouton" or "pointe de menton". "bouton" is correct in French but I have never heard about "pointe de menton" before. Is it a correct translation? And if yes, could you pinpoint me to an exemple where it is used?

Comment: Never heard that, I guess it is a weirdness of the translator.

Comment: ok, I have wrote a message to the "academie francaise", we'll see.

Comment: Who / what gave you that translation? Is it a reliable source? La *pointe du menton* means "the tip  of the chin".  What kind of button are you talking about ? "Button" is very vague, straight away, I have 5 different meanings that come to my mind for button t(here might be more...  and there are different words for them in French !

Comment: google translate and a couple of others.

Comment: Google translate is no good. Any serious dictionary in "these couple of others? Tried [Reverso](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/anglais-francais/button/) or [Linguee](http://www.linguee.fr/anglais-francais/traduction/button.html)? You should give context in your question so that we know what kind of button you are talking about.

Comment: nope, just google translate, mydictionary.net, dictionarist.com, ..They probably relies the one on each others. Ok, I have my answer, it is incorrect. I was thinking that maybe it could be a canadian or old french expression.

Comment: Even Google ngram give no results for ["pointe de menton"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pointe+de+menton%2Cpointe+du+menton&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpointe%20du%20menton%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Which kind of "bouton" are you actually referring to ? "Bouton" has multiple meanings in French related to clothes, flowers, pimple,... Although I must say I never heard "pointe de menton" as something even vaguely related to "bouton"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short answer

**No, it is not correct, you should use *"bouton"***.

---

### Why not?

The word *[menton](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/menton)* is the chin.

The word *[pointe](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pointe)* has the meaning of *"A sharp extremity"* ([2. meaning](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/point)).

So, *"pointe de menton"* (or more exactly *"pointe du menton"* as @Circeus underlined) may be a reference to the extreme part of the chin.

---

### The reason

Now, why does it translate *button* into *"pointe de menton"*?

Maybe because, in french we call *"[boutons](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bouton#French)"* the pimples. And everyone knows that they often set up there.

Comment: @YCR Don't hesitate to tell me the context in which you want to use *"bouton"*, I may update my answer to better fit your need.

Comment: I am ok with the translation button - bouton. It is just the translation "pointe de menton" which let me sceptic.